# Typhoon Swift Factory Method Missing

Tags: ios, typhoon

When I try to inject parameters using the following method, the Xcode compiler says it cannot invoke this method. It works fine if I remove the 
configuration parameter. Xcode intellisense doesn't list out this method either.
Am I missing something thing here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using a factory component with trailing closure syntax. Just about all of the TyphoonDefinition methods have the block/closure as the last parameter, so you can use the traling closure syntax. I find this a little easier to read in Swift.

```
public dynamic func motherOfKnights() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(MotherOfKnights.self)
}

public dynamic func brandNewBabyKnight() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withFactory(self.motherOfKnights(), 
      selector: "makeKnight:") {
        (factoryMethod) in

        factoryMethod.injectParameterWith("Robert")
    }
}
```